# Setting up Harbor registry in Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to set up a Harbor Registry in Kubernetes cluster locally in Minikube. I am using https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm and trying to set it up with the ingress controller. At the moment, I have not changed any defaults (the default is of type 'ingress') but have installed the Nginx Ingress Controller via `minikube addons enable ingress`.

Right now, the helm chart installs, and I added an entry to my hosts file for `192.168.49.2 core.harbor.domain` but page simply returns a 503 error.

When reviewing the pod logs for the harbor portal, I get this: `ginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:8080 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)`

I'm pretty sure that the reason why I'm getting this is because I need some default values set when installing the chart, but I'm not really sure what those may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the issue was: I needed to set the `ipFamily.ipv6.enabled` version to false:

`helm upgrade -i my-release harbor/harbor --set ipFamily.ipv6.enabled=false`